# Using PHP to redirect if page takes too long to load

Tags: php

Is there any way with PHP to redirect a page if it's taking too long to load?

For example, I have a PHP file that check a bunch of details about a domain name.  Sometimes it'll get hung up in various stages of the script - sometimes while curling the domain, other times while running a whois query on it.

Regardless of why the script gets hung up, is there any way to say "if this takes longer than 15 seconds, redirect to another URL?"

I was looking at PHP headers, but I think those would be sent before the script starts running, I wasn't sure if you could send redirect headers throughout the script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The better approach here would be to do this action via ajax

Comment: You can put a timeout on the curl connection itself. See the [`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option.

Comment: question is a bit unclear , *”i have a PHP file that check a bunch of details about a domain name.”*  What does it check database or Whois server? ... Add PHP code so a can make better suggestions and see how your code works

Comment: You can send redirect headers as long as you have nothing outputting to the page yet.